# doesn't get correct json from post request using rest console django

Tags: python, json, django, rest

when i,m going to fetch the json from google chrome's advanced rest console POST request i'm getting my whole data as a key and empty string as a value

my json is :

```
{
    "school_id" : "1",
    "registration_no" : "",
    "first_name" : "Anmol",
    "middle_name" : "987686853",
    "last_name" : "",
    "student_category_id" : "null",
    "date_of_birth" : "1991-01-01",
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "street_address" : "",
    "student_city" : "",
    "student_state" : "",
    "student_country" : "",
    "pin_code" : "",
    "religion" : "",
    "nationality" : "",
    "phone_number" : "",
    "mobile_number" : "987686853",
    "email" : "ab@cd.ef",
    "previous_institution_name" : "BFCET",
    "board" : "g",
    "latest_course" : "grapes",
    "passing_year" : "675",
    "percentage_marks" : "56",
    "course" : "1",
    "batch" : "2",
    "image" : "null",
    "is_active" :" true"
}
```

to fetch this json i'm using the code in my views.py file:

```
def create(self, request):

        data=request.POST
        print data
        print "school_id",data.get('school_id')
```

but by this i'm getting MultiValueDictKeyError error:

i'm using django restframework ,python.

Comment: Did you print data. What is there in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import json`
and `data=json.loads(request.body)` instead of `data=request.POST`

Your data will be there in `request.body`. I am assuming this is not a form submit Ajax call.